# AT command, sms received is in hex format

Tags: at-command

We are working on a modem, to send and receive SMSs. It was working well till i faced a problem where the received SMS is split in two messagse and is hex format

I have set the mode to TEXT MODE using AT+CMGF=1 but still no luck,

The messages are not accurate even if joint and hex decoded.

This is the recieved SMS,

+CMGL: 1,"REC UNREAD","55501",,"16/04/13,00:46:10+22"
702B2040373038333134333333342C20527320323530302C20484C52202D342C2039373633333134
3331342C20527320323530302C20484C52202D312C20373038333731343333342C20527320323530

+CMGL: 2,"REC UNREAD","55501",,"16/04/13,00:46:11+22"
702BAD40332C205273203134392C20484C52202D332C204E756D6265

Im using a wavecom modem, help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you ever solve this? I have the same problem

Answer (score -1):

set AT+CMGF=1
it will convert it into text